# Translation of a passage

Tags: translation-check, latin-to-english-translation

In a book that I'm reading, a [passage](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=zwRAAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA481&lpg=PA481&dq=%22quam%20scripturam%20quamdam%22&source=bl&ots=3fOwcTeUlH&sig=ACfU3U2bjqvAzH-JqTJohvz0DPThHxgTLw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiH17Ofw8zqAhXMDOwKHW5iBkQQ6AEwAXoECAsQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22quam%20scripturam%20quamdam%22&f=false) form Johann Gottlieb Heineccius is referred to illustrate the difference between *codicilli* and *epistolae* (the last paragraph [starting: "unde recte"] is the problematic part, but to give more context I lay here the entire passage):

> *Codicilli* voce nihil Romani denotabant aliud, quam scripturam quamdam ad alios missam. Hinc saepe *codicillos* pro *epistolis* ponit Cicero epist. ad Fam. IV 13; VI. 18. ad Quint. Fratr. II. 11.
> Praecipue tamen id  nomen tribuebatur epistolis ad praesentes missis,
> italice: *viglietti*. Unde Seneca ep. LV:

> "Video te, mi Lucili, quum maxime audio, adeo tecum sum, ut dubitem, an incipiam non *epistolas* sed *codicillos* tibi scribere"

> Unde recte colligas codicillos, quos deinde imperatores tamquam ultimae voluntatis genus adprobarunt, nihil aliud  fuisse quam epistolas scriptas ad haeredes de eo, quod post mortem suam scribentes ab haeredibus fieri vellent.
> Heineccius lib. II. A. R. p. 543.

My free-translation so far:

> For the Romans, *Codicilli* denoted nothing else but a certain writing that is sent to others. Therefore Cicero sometimes uses *Codicilli* instead of *epistola*. Yet, chiefly, this name [*codicilli*] is given to letters that are sent to those in presence. from this Seneca: [citation that illustrates that is *Codicilli* and not *epistola* that being sent to the closed one ("adeo tecum sum")].

But now is the part I'm struggling with and too-far from understanding(which is maybe a citation from another source at least partially):

> (from there/where) you are, correctly, collecting *codicillos*, whom Imperators(?), ["tamquam ultimae voluntatis genus adprobarunt"], nothing but written *epistolas* to his heirs which after his death, writing (the imporatores?) as they wish to become among the heirs.

Not even sure who are the players in this paragraph or what "tamquam ultimae voluntatis genus" means in the context [and even when it stand-alone], is *eo* and *suam* can relate to the same person or should account for 2 different?

Comment: I assume that "italice: viglietti" refers to the word which in modern Italian is biglietti, French billets, in the sense "notes passed from one person to another".

Comment: @fdb, indeed Wiktionary confirms this. It also says the french *billets* is from the Latin *bulla* (that could mean in medieval times a seal of a document, or the document itself)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Unde recte colligas codicillos, quos deinde imperatores tamquam ultimae voluntatis genus adprobarunt, nihil aliud fuisse quam epistolas scriptas ad haeredes de eo, quod post mortem suam scribentes ab haeredibus fieri vellent. Heineccius lib. II. A. R. p. 543.

"And from this you may conclude/summarise correctly that codicils, which the Emperors later established/sanctioned as (if they were) a kind of last will, were nothing else but letters written to heirs about what they, writing after their own death, wanted done from their heirs."

I think *colligo* must mean "conclude, summarise", because "collect" wouldn't make sense in context.

"The Emperors" can refer to legal system and customs instituted by or common during the Roman Empire, as opposed to the preceding Republic. The passage can be read such that it was the Emperors themselves who instituted this practice, by leaving letters to their own heirs (otherwise, we have a dangling subject "they" in the *quo* clause).

Note that a *tamquam* clause is normally subjunctive, and most subordinate clauses depending on an accusativus cum infinitivo are also normally in the subjunctive.

*Suus* can refer to any antecedent in the third person, including a plural like the Emperors.

*De eo* is to be translated by "about that" as normal. *Quod* is a relative pronoun referring back to *eo*, so "about that which... / about what...".

*Fieri* must be translated as the passive of *facere* here, rather than the alternative ("to become"): so it should be "to be done". *Quod vellent fieri* is then "what they wanted (to be) done".

The praeposition *a(b(s))* means "by, from" here.

Comment: Thanks for detailed response! How far I got it ... alas.

Comment: By the way, my second-hand source, from which I transcribed the text says "Codicilli voce nihil **Romani** denotabant", while the original [source](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=qr4oAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA465&lpg=PA465&dq=quam+scripturam+quamdam+ad+alios+missam+veteres&source=bl&ots=mrZXy6wrjc&sig=ACfU3U2GRXAcq62Oz_eeoClYZZCerAsY3w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiksMW6k83qAhXvl4sKHU5nDgIQ6AEwAHoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=quam%20scripturam%20quamdam%20ad%20alios%20missam%20veteres&f=false)  says "**Veteres**"  instead of "Romani". Which indeed makes this clearer.

Comment: Note that *colligas* is subjunctive, so "you *would* correctly conclude..."

Comment: @TKR: Ah, of course. What would be the best translation? *Would* might suggest an irrealis? I'm not entirely sure about the conventions of translating into English. A potentialis can be expressed as *could/might*? Alternatively, an adhortativus "should" is possible. I feel that perhaps *would* fits the context best, but I'm not sure whether it is possible with a present subjunctive.

Comment: I was using *would* as an implied apodosis ("if you were to conclude this, you would conclude correctly"), but *might/could* seem equally good. A jussive *should* seems less suitable to me in this context, since you wouldn't normally order someone to "conclude correctly".

Comment: @TKR: *"If you were to..., you would..."* sounds a bit like an irrealis? I would not normally treat a present subjunctive as irrealis, but perhaps this translation can be used to render a potentialis as well in English? Or maybe it's the 'trivial' kind of modern irrealis. Oh, well. I agree that *should* is unsuitable if only because of *recte*. I'll go with *may* for the moment.

Comment: Apodosis of a future less vivid is what I was thinking with "If you were...". But *may* seems like an excellent choice.